# Advice needed for Basic Matlab Vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a code which I would like to vectorize.

I'm abit new with matlab and not sure how to approach the problem.

Each variable( S, X, r, T, v,Type) is a 200x1 single, and this is the code I'd like to vectorize:

```
function [Delta] = bsdelta( S, X, r, T, v,Type)



d1=(log(S/X)+(r+v.^2/2)*T)/(v*sqrt(T));
            %if Call      
        if Type == 1 
           Delta = normcdf(d1)         ;    
            %if Put          
        elseif Type == 0     
           Delta = normcdf(d1)-1;
        end

end
```

I know it's a rather basic question, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `Type` is also 200 x 1 vector? Not sure, what is that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you use the `matrix division` operation `/` when you intend (I think) to do an `element by element` division - `./` . This is a subtle but very very important distinction.

If you have two vectors, X and Y, you could take their dot product with

```
s = 0;
for ii = 1:numel(X)
  s = s + X(ii) * Y(ii);
end
```

After this, the sum of the products is in variable `s`. Much faster would be:

```
s = sum(X.*Y);
```

Where the `.*` operation means "do the product one element at a time".  With vectors, the other possibility is

```
s = X(:)' * Y(:);
```

This turns `X` into a row vector, and `Y` into a column vector, then performs matrix multiplication (element by element multiply, followed by a sum).

But now take a look at your code:

```
function [Delta] = bsdelta( S, X, r, T, v,Type)

  d1=(log(S/X)+(r+v.^2/2)*T)/(v*sqrt(T));
  %if Call      
    if Type == 1 
      Delta = normcdf(d1)         ;    
        %if Put          
    elseif Type == 0     
      Delta = normcdf(d1)-1;
    end
end
```

You show no attempt to recognize that there are 200 elements in each of these, and I'm pretty sure the result will be wrong. If, as I suspect, you want to do element-by-element processing, you could do:

```
 d1 = (log(S./X)+(r+v.^2/2).*T)./(v.*sqrt(T));
```

This should result in a 200 element array `d1`.  Now we need to apply the function:

```
Delta = normcdf(d1);
```

And finally, subtract `1` if `Type == 1`:

```
Delta(Type==0) = Delta(Type==0) - 1;
```

If you wanted to be more concise, you could actually replace those two lines with

```
Delta = normcdf(d1) - double((Type == 0));
```

Since the boolean operation `Type == 0` would result in a `1` if true and `0` if false. I explicitly cast the result to `double` so that it's clear to anyone reading this code later that I intentionally mixed the result of a boolean operation with an arithmetic operation.

Comment: Thanks for your concise and informative response.
 
I have made the changes you recommended to my code, and that has solved my problem.

Appreciate the advice,

Live long and prosper!

Comment: @BenTam64 - glad I could help. Matlab is powerful, but it takes some getting used to. And then you try Python and all the rules change…

Comment: Hmm, I will look into Python. 

Matlab's really useful, and I'm still learning. 

Thanks for the help along the way. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Python is very powerful, has a ton of free third party support, is free and available on many platforms. I have been a huge Matlab user for years but am starting to learn Python as an alternative now - but coming from Matlab you need to "unlearn" a lot - things just work very, very differently in Python (people talk about "pythonic" as an adjective for "the way you do things in Python" - it really needs its own word to describe it...). The `numpy` and `scipy` modules help a lot in the transition from Matlab... Bottom line - use what feels right (and gets the job done).